# password_verify won't work

Tags: php, hash

Heres my code:
-- registered.php -- this file sends the new users username and password to the database

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<?php 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['password'];
    $defaultrank = "user";
    $password=password_hash($mypassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
?>


<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) { ?>
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO usr (username, password, email, rank)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$defaultrank')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { ?>


<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=register.php#registrationsuccess" />

<?php }
else{ ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=register.php#registrationfailed" />
<?php } ?>





<?php $conn->close(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

-- redir.php -- This sends the login info to the database to be verified

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$host="localhost";
$user="root"; 
$pass="root"; 
$db="usr";  
$tbl="usr"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
include 'registered.php';

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$user = $myusername;
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$pass = $mypassword;
// $password=md5($mypassword);
$hashAndSalt = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$savemyusername = $myusername;
$savemypassword = $mypassword;

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE username='$myusername' and password='password_verify($password, $hashAndSalt)'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
// Sessions //
$_SESSION["pass"] = $pass;
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
// END //
echo <<<EOF
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=membersarea.php" />
EOF;
}

else { ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=login.php#loginfailed" />
<?php 
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The login system works fine with md5
Also the data from registered.php gets sent hashed to the database, its just verifying the data which is the problem

Comment: Those are some lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Did you intend for your login system to absolutely useless and trivially by-passable?

Comment: ironic mix of password hashing and a 20th century MySQL API.

Comment: this is failing you btw `password='password_verify($password, $hashAndSalt)'` - having the intended function used as a string literal.

Comment: FYI: MD5 produces a string length of 32 characters. password_hash 60.

Comment: Marc thats going to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT [..snip..] and password='password_verify($password, $hashAndSalt)'";
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You cannot embed PHP code in a string and expect PHP to execute it, nor will MySQl execute PHP code for you, since MySQL has absolutely no idea what PHP is.

Even if that php function call did magically somehow get executed, it can only ever return a boolean value, so your code would (in the magic kingdom) boil down to two possiblities:

```
... password = false
... password = true
```

Comment: How would I do it, put it into a var and then put the var there or???

Comment: select the hash out of the sdb, then `if (password_verify($password, $hash_from_db))`, which is purely a PHP thing.

Comment: I want to do that but I'm not too sure how to actually get the hash from the database

Comment: you `select ...` it, like you would any other data in a db...